# with expression vs new keyword

Tags: c#, heap-memory, c#-9.0

I was reading the [devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/) about "what's new in C#9.0", then I noticed "with expression".

```
public data class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
var otherPerson = person with { LastName = "Hanselman" };
```

they say

> A record implicitly defines a protected “copy constructor” – a
>   constructor that takes an existing record object and copies it field
>   by field to the new one:

```
protected Person(Person original) { /* copy all the fields */ } // generated
```

> The with expression causes the copy constructor to get called, and
>   then applies the object initializer on top to change the properties
>   accordingly.

My question is ,
 Does "with" copy the whole old objects from "Heap" and then modify them with new values (if exists) and then make new instance? (IMO...I think this is expensive approach) 
or Does "with" make you write less lines ONLY without any memory leaks?

if my first assumption were right, would it be better to use "with" or "new" like: `var obj = new foo();`

Comment: *"and then make new instance"* - No. A second new instance is not created, only the first one where the values are modified. -- Gareth's answer is correct, but it doesn't clarify this point.

Comment: so "with expression" make the class acts like a store ? every time we declare a new obj it goes to Person and returns a NEW modified instance of it?

Comment: Every `with` expression creates one new instance from the old one. Don't do `person with {FirstName="John"} with {LastName="Doe"}` if you don't want extra allocations. Do `person with {FirstName="John", LastName="Doe"}` and you get just one allocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `with` expression creates a new instance, so the old instance will still exist unchanged, it does no mutation—this makes sense, given the intent is for working with immutable data.

This is not a memory leak, unless you keep the old instances around somehow. It may increase GC churn, but that isn't necessarily a bad thing, and the gains in the ease of reasoning from immutability can often be worth that cost.

(Of course, I assume there is potential for optimization from the compiler here, if the compiler can prove the old value won't be used, but I doubt such a thing is implemented—yet at the very least).

Edit:

Here is [a SharpLab decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEBMBGAsAKFygZgAIE4BjAewQBMiAFRKCgOyIG9ciujCeMAGIgDEAlglgA5CGDjsiAczgwA3ERHMRKogF9O3XigFEAMtBhSZcxVvWbVunNyJ6uBgCxEAsgAoAlOxcnIgA3CAQiAAdGFiIAXiJmOAB3emjWNmExSWlZeIAiABU4WDyAGhMzCzhYwuKYPJ1lQKdQ8IoYAAtEBnEY+Kje1iTNDrlTbMt8gAkIZig4ABtIZgbtJscg1wwATm92roQepmZfdacHBydcZhyoCIgyWUMAOgAlAFdmGBEZZ4BhChgCIiBaIADKiGCIkeUDk6CIAEkoABRAAe8AQNwWCI0MDk2h0QA=) (with a few changes to get it working). You can see that it is quite simple stuff it compiles down to.

Comment: Easy way to tell would be to mock up a sharplab example using the "with" branch and check the generated c# tab. I'd do it and provide a link but hard to do from a cell phone

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yeah, I was looking into that. There are a few changes needed to get it working on SharpLab, but I've added it.

Comment: thanks for sharpLab decompilation it makes the answer completely clear.

Comment: @GarethLatty, Out of curiosity, what does `namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices { class IsExternalInit { } }` do on the SharpLab input code?

Comment: @KyleMit That was necessary at the time to get records working on the version of C# on SharpLab. I imagine it no longer is.