# C# 9.0 With-expressions. How to use them?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

The new C# 9.0 syntax allows for a new kind of expression:

```
var newPerson = oldPerson with { Age = "21" };
```

Following questions arise when looking at the previous code line:

1. Is it a reference or a new object copy?
2. If it's a reference, what about the inheritance? Consider the following code line:

```
Person child = new Child{ FirstName = "Jan", LastName = "Brown", IsInKindergarten = false };
Person person = child with { LastName = "Williams" }
```

Does the compiler allow the `person` object to inherit the `IsInKindergarten` property?

Comment: [with expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#with-expressions) is explained pretty clear _to create new values from existing ones to represent a new state_

Comment: records and with expressions are not in the final stage, i have seen some people jump on to preview langauge features too soon and get burnt

Comment: Related: [with expression vs new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418120/with-expression-vs-new-keyword)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks for the article! Kinda missed that.. Still, the inheritance issue was unclear to me till it was confirmed in the answer.

Comment: For anyone else wondering how the heck this can possibly work without breaking encapsulation, it only works on a new kind of thing called a *record*, which is identified by declaring the class with the new keyword `data`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case `var newPerson = oldPerson with { Age = "21" };` it creates a new object that’s a copy of the old one, except with a different age.

> Does the compiler allow the person object to inherit the
>   IsInKindergarten property?

yes, the `person` will be `FirstName = "Jan", LastName = "Williams", IsInKindergarten = false`

Answer (score 1):

this syntax about record in c# 9.0 and this is Immutable type indeed all immutable types are creating new object like as struct
for more information about this you can see this
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/C-9-Language-Features

Comment: i am an Amateur take it easy